# How about the docker run in virtul machine best practice?

Tags: mongodb, docker

How about the docker run in virtul machine best practice?

---

> PS:
>   anybody has the docker run in kvm virtul machine on the production?
>   or run in AWS and other cloud platform?

for example,I building the mongodb in docker container and deploy it on the production envirment apply to provider data for a PV 100,000,000/day SNS community .

what about the performance ?

it's no recommend to use docker in virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a process isolated with namespace and cgroup. It is a Operating system level virtualization and haven't any association with virtual machine. You can use with virtual hardware or bare metal without difference.

Comment: Thanks, for this case, I worry about building the mongodb instance in docker with virtul machine will be low performance . such as  I/O  and so on, I have not any experience about that , could you give me some suggest ?

Comment: Using Docker or not has the same I/O performance. You need tunning your machine (virtual or not)  to get better performance.